# Resizing, flushing and closing ByteBuffer

Tags: java, flush, memory-mapped-files, mappedbytebuffer

These are actually three questions about how to work with memory mapped files. What I did works, but I'm missing an authoritative answer.

I obtain my `ByteBuffer` like follows:

```
raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, isReadonly ? "r" : "rw");
channel = raf.getChannel();
buffer = channel.map(mode, 0, channel.size());
```

For resizing, the following seems to work

```
raf.setLength(newLength);
channel = raf.getChannel();
```

without calling `raf.getChannel()`, but *is it really correct?*

---

According to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html#force()), calling `force` should flush it (I'm using a local drive). I just wonder how it comes that it declares no `IOException` and *what happens if it fails?*

---

What do I have to close? The `RandomAccessFile`, the `FileChannel`, or both of them? Do I have to call some `flush` or `MappedByteBuffer.force` before?

Answer (score 1):

> For resizing, the following seems to work

```
raf.setLength(newLength);
channel = raf.getChannel();
```

> without calling raf.getChannel(), but is it really correct?

Yes. You don't need to reacquire the channel. It's still valid after `setLength()`.

> According to the Javadoc, calling `force()` should flush it (I'm using a local drive). I just wonder how it comes that it declares no `IOException` and what happens if it fails?

You appear to be talking here about [MappedByteBuffer.force()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html#force--). I cannot explain the designer's choices.

> What do I have to close? The RandomAccessFile, the FileChannel, or both of them?

Any of them.

> Do I have to call some `flush()` or `MappedByteBuffer.force()` before?

There is no `flush()`. You can call `force()` if you like, otherwise the changes may be delayed.